# Diff file list from Magento 2.1.7 to 2.1.8

Tags: magento-2.1

Is there a diff file list of Magento v2.1.7 and v2.1.8?

Because I have overwritten some Core-Files in template. 
For example minicart.js this resulted in a not functioning minicart. I fixed the problem, now I am not sure if there exists any other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GitHub to compare tags:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/compare/2.1.7...2.1.8#files_bucket

Comment: thx for info. Is it correct that composer updates more or less the files in folder "vendor" of magento?

Comment: Yes, mostly, but some files are also copied outside, e.g. to `dev` and `lib`. To find out, which, look at the `map` section in `vendor/magento/magento2-base/composer.json`. This is a special package type  `magento2-component` which is designed to install files outside of the vendor directory.